# Async Await not waiting as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I swore I had this working and then changed some things and can't quite get it.
i have an express controller that has this piece of code:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  myModule.organizationLookup(req.body.domain).then((data) => {
    res.status(200).send(data);
  })
});
```

then my problem code: myModule.js looks like this:

```
myModule.organizationLookup = (domain) => {
  async function getOrganization(domain) {
    try {
      return await thirdpartySDK.Company.find({domain: domain});
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  getOrganization(domain);
};
```

It always throws an error in the controller:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: That's because you're not returning anything to `organizationLookup`, you're calling inside `getOrganization(domain)` but not returning that value.

Comment: Also I don't see the point of using `async/await` if you're gonna return a promise.

Comment: actual code is more complex, overly simplifying for this post

Comment: Right, good luck I posted my answer.

Comment: @Gerardo - `async/await` is syntactic sugar for Promise's, so your statement about the point of using async/await looks odd

Comment: @JaromandaX I know what it is and it looks cleaner but what I wanted to say is that if `thirdpartySDK.Company.find({domain: domain})` returns a Promise why not returning it directly to `organizationLookup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a superfluous function in there whose result you don't `return`. Just drop the function and write

```
myModule.organizationLookup = async function getOrganization(domain) {
  try {
    return await thirdpartySDK.Company.find({domain: domain});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```

Comment: You've got a superflous function name of which you don't reference! `async (domain) =>` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Crowes Right :-) I thought maybe for some reason the OP wanted to name the function (he says that his actual code is more complex).